# How to send Email using sitecore form in sitecore 9.0.1

Tags: sitecore-forms, exm

I am using sitecore 9.0.1 with sxa 1.7.We have requirement to send the mail once the user get registered.
For that i have created a sitecore form with submit action with save data and redirect page and i also need to send a email to the user.

I have created a Automated Email Campaign in EXM with "TestEmail" as a name and test mail was working while creating a Automated Email campaign ,but when i attach that mail to submit button its not working. Can someone help me with that.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Code for rendering Form:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Assets/Form.css" />
    <title>
        @Html.Sitecore().Field("title", new { DisableWebEdit = true })
    </title>
    @Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification() 
    @Html.RenderFormStyles() 
    @Html.RenderFormScripts()
</head>

<body> @RenderBody() </body>

</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120656/discussion-on-question-by-vinaya-how-to-send-email-using-sitecore-form-in-siteco).

Comment: can you try putting redirect to page submit action in the end. Basically, we should redirect after completing all other actions on submit.